# Complex query for returning an email conversation list

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a complex query that is not working in this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b1cf7/1).

In the app I work for, we sync users Gmail with our database.  We store emails in an emails table and we also have a replies table where we store a the references header that lists all the parent replies for an email.

So for example, if I have an email like this:

```
id  | subject     | message_id
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | howzitgoin  | 53856b1448c89_23fa9605badd015951@3a139e8c-0b81-42c2-8e59-133c262e96a9.mail
```

There would be no records in the replies table:

Now if we import a reply for this email like this:

```
    id  | subject     | message_id  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2   | RE: howzitgoin  | CAEBV8YTu_A6LtP_uGuQ-QSVj3zojWUiwcjGZpsPPEz1Pj3_i1A@mail.gmail.com
```

We would store the following in the replies table:

```
    email_id | message_id
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       2     | 53856b1448c89_23fa9605badd015951@3a139e8c-0b81-42c2-8e59-133c262e96a9.mail
```

And if we received a reply to this:

```
id  | subject     | message_id
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3   | RE: howzitgoin  | 53856b88a2a09_23fa9605badd01601b@3a139e8c-0b81-42c2-8e59-133c262e96a9.mail
```

we would store the following in the replies table:

```
email_id | message_id
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     | 53856b1448c89_23fa9605badd015951@3a139e8c-0b81-42c2-8e59-133c262e96a9.mail
   3     | CAEBV8YTu_A6LtP_uGuQ-QSVj3zojWUiwcjGZpsPPEz1Pj3_i1A@mail.gmail.com
```

After much head scratching, I came up with this query:

```
    WITH "ranked_replies" AS 
    (
        SELECT "r"."email_id", "r"."message_id", "rnk" 
        FROM (SELECT *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY "message_id" ORDER BY "email_id" DESC) AS "rnk" FROM "replies") AS "r" 
        INNER JOIN "emails" 
        ON ("emails"."message_id" = "r"."message_id") 
    ), 
    "count_of_replies" AS 
    (
        SELECT "email_id", count(*) AS "count", count(*) AS "thread_count" 
        FROM "ranked_replies" 
        GROUP BY "email_id"
    ) 
    SELECT DISTINCT "emails".*, "thread_count" 
    FROM "emails" 
    LEFT JOIN "count_of_replies" 
    ON ("emails"."id" = "count_of_replies"."email_id") 
    WHERE 
    (
        ("folder" = 'INBOX') 
        AND 
        (
            ("emails"."message_id" NOT IN (SELECT "message_id" FROM "ranked_replies" WHERE ("rnk" != 1))) 

            OR ("emails"."message_id" IS NULL)
        ) 
        AND ("emails"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "email_id" FROM "ranked_replies" WHERE ("rnk" != 1)))
    ) 
    ORDER BY "created_at" DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

The problem is that it is not returning the email thread that has the subject of 'not returning'.

The reason for this is because of this part of the where clause:

```
("emails"."message_id" NOT IN (SELECT "message_id" FROM "ranked_replies" WHERE ("rnk" != 1))
```

This excludes the root email with the subject of 'not returning' because it has 2 rows in ranked_replies with rank 1 and 2.

I want a query that:

1. Show E-Mails that have no replies to them (e.G. not in threads)
2. Show the Top end of each Thread, if multiple end nodes of each thread exist I only want one.
3. Show only E-Mails that are in the current folder (Inbox).

Referring the SQLFiddle example: It should return the E-Mails: #5 (highest ranking of thread 1), #8 (highest ranking of thread 2), #9 (not in thread) and #10 (not highest ranking, but only one of thread in inbox)

I'm having trouble with the #10.

Comment: Replace the `NOT IN (...)` by the corresponding `NOT EXISTS(...)` construct.

Comment: will that not have the same result?

Comment: Depends on the nullability. My guess is that your message_id can never be NULL, but you did not give the table structure.

Comment: the table structure is in the sql fiddle at the start of the post

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that.

Comment: Do you want to display every message, which hasn't replied (yet), or you want to display every thread's last message? And if you want the latter, how do you want to handle those situations, when a thread divides into multiple threads? -- f.ex. in your fiddle, the messages with `id` of `4` and `5` (*Re: howzitgoin*) both replies to the `3`, but not replies to each other.

Comment: If you think of how mail is displayed in GMail then that is the required format.

If the record is part of a thread then it displays the most recent mail in the tread and has a count of the number of records in the thread.  If I can't get an accurate count then just knowing it is part of a thread is fine.

If the record is not part of a thread then it is just displayed.

Comment: Why do you store the message-id of the thread-starter in the replies-table, and not just its numerical id (since it is already present in the emails-table)? You could even combine the two tables, and put the parent_id directly into the messasges table. Also: what is the need for the `folder='INBOX'` term in the where clause?

Comment: you are right I think.  The fact that the storage uses the message_id was a bad idea.  It is used also when replying to an email on the imap side of things but I think this was a bad design choice.

The folder="inbox" part of the query is because we display the users list of emails in either their "inbox" or "sent" folders

Comment: I am open to changing the table structure.

Comment: Can a reply refer to **only one** email, or can it refer **multiple** previous emails in the same thread ? (in your sample data: only one: the thread starter)

Comment: when you receive an email, it contains a references header which contains a list of all the parent email's message_ids or the reply thread of emails before this reply.  This way you can get all the previous emails for any email.  I chose to store the data in exactly this way which was probably not a good idea.

Comment: If there can be more than one reference you need the second table. It would probably be a good idea to store the {numerical_id, message_id} in a third *domain* lookup table, to be used for both local and incoming message_id's. BTW: what is *the purpose* of your query? Just showing *all* emails in a threaded way?

Comment: yes, I want to show the user's email inbox of emails in the same way as gmail shows its inbox of emails

Comment: I don't know how gmail shows its inbox. Please be more specific / explicit.

Comment: The fact that email with id=3 is a reply to email with id=3 is an error or I misunderstood something

Comment: Could you please explain what kind of entity corresponds to each line in the replies table and, in particular, what the email_id column stands for?

Comment: Your fiddle being in Postgres 9.2 tells us you are using that version? Or by mistake and you really mean 9.3? Your (unchanged) fiddle without all the noise: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/243f4/1

Comment: no, we are using 9.2.6

Comment: @dagda1 I included the expectation you have on the query as best as I understood it in your question. If I got it wrong, please fix it as you see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Not returning" E-Mails are not returning because the top one has replies, and the lower ones are not in the "Inbox".

As a sidenode: As you have this as an "app" I suppose you could enhance it by transferring the metadata of all (at least until a specific amount) mails to the clients and do the sorting / filtering there. That will most likely scale better (and be quicker in user experience) than having the database do all the thinking, depending on userbase etc. Back to your question:

I'm quite uncertain on why you use `rank()` for this anyway, so I dropped it. If you want to continue using it because of other requirements that I overlooked you can do so: Use rank on a subselect on "replies" that only handles rows where the replies are in the current folder.

Maybe you want to skip the selection of the "threadid" in my solution and solve this by inserting this id in the first place. Or you create a unique id per thread yourself.

As I don't know the gmail way of showing mails I assume you want the following:

1. Show E-Mails that have no replies to them (e.G. not in threads)
2. Show the Top end of each Thread, if multiple end nodes of each thread exist I assume you only want one.
3. Care only about E-Mails in the current folder.

I created [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/73b08/12/0) that does that.
In there I also changed you database model to reference the message that is replied to by its primary key (id) instead of its message_id.
As this is a numerical sequence it can be used to address the thread tree and I did so.

This is the solution:

```
WITH "thread" AS 
( -- select the uppermost id per thread
    SELECT r."email_id", min("reply_to_id") AS "threadid"
    FROM "replies" r
    INNER JOIN "emails" e ON r.email_id = e.id 
    -- create tree only for current folder
    AND e.folder = 'INBOX'
    GROUP BY r."email_id"
),
"lastmail" AS
( -- select the highest email per thread
  SELECT t."threadid", max(r."email_id") AS "lastmail"
  FROM replies r
  INNER JOIN thread t ON t.threadid = r.reply_to_id
  GROUP BY t."threadid"
),
"count_of_replies" AS
(SELECT r."email_id", count(r.*) AS "thread_count"
 FROM replies r
  INNER JOIN thread t ON t.threadid = r.reply_to_id
  GROUP BY r."email_id")
SELECT DISTINCT "emails".*, "thread_count"
FROM "emails" 
LEFT JOIN "count_of_replies" 
ON ("emails"."id" = "count_of_replies"."email_id") 
WHERE 
(
   -- only from current folder
    ("folder" = 'INBOX') AND
    (
      -- the ones that are in no thread
      ("emails"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "email_id" FROM "thread"
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT "threadid" from "thread"))
      OR
      -- the ones that are top in their thread
      ("emails"."id" IN (SELECT "lastmail" FROM "lastmail"))
    )
) 
ORDER BY "created_at" DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If, as the comments suggest, you're open to changing the schema, and you're looking for the gmail list I'm looking at as I write, consider something like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE emails
(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  thread_id serial NOT NULL,
  parent_id int REFERENCES emails (id),
  subject text,
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  folder text,
  message_id text
);
```

With this schema you could then get the latest post of each thread along with the count of emails in each thread without using any joins: a simple scan with a window function will do.

When your app doesn't set `thread_id`, it'll increment automatically and thus yield a new thread. This will further allow you to split a thread in two if needed in the future.

If you want to optimize the schema further, add an extra two columns, namely `is_latest` and `num_messages`:

```
CREATE TABLE emails
(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id int REFERENCES emails (id),
  thread_id serial NOT NULL,
  is_latest boolean NOT NULL default true,
  num_messages int NOT NULL default 1,
  subject text,
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  folder text,
  message_id text
);
```

Then, use:

1. A before insert trigger on rows where `parent_id is not null or num_messages = 0`, select the latest from the thread, and set `new.num_messages` to that row's `num_messages + 1`.
2. An after insert trigger, update the other rows from the thread and apply the needed side-effects, aka set `is_latest` and `num_messages`.
3. Before and after triggers on update and delete statements to similarly maintain the two columns as appropriate when e.g. an email is deleted, its date is changed, or it and its siblings are moved to a different thread.

Note: Do NOT put side-effects that affect other rows on before triggers, and be wary of making triggers loop in the update triggers.

With this optimized schema you'll be able to place a partial index on created_at where `is_latest`, and collect all of the needed information without using any joins, aggregates or window functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE emails
        ADD COLUMN thread_id INTEGER REFERENCES emails(id)
        , ADD COLUMN previous_id INTEGER REFERENCES emails(id)
        ;
        -- Initially, all messages are in their own private thread.
UPDATE emails SET thread_id = id;


WITH www AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT email_id AS email_id
        -- Find the oldest and newest reference per id
        , first_value(e.id) OVER w AS mmin
        , last_value(e.id) OVER w AS mmax
        FROM replies r
        JOIN emails e ON e.message_id = r.message_id
        WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY r.email_id ORDER BY e.created_at ASC)
        )
UPDATE emails dst
SET thread_id = www.mmin
        , previous_id = www.mmax
FROM www
WHERE dst.id = www.email_id
        ;


SELECT  id, thread_id, previous_id
        , rank() over (PARTITION BY thread_id ORDER BY created_at) AS rnk
        , subject, created_at, folder ,message_id
FROM emails
ORDER BY thread_id,created_at,id;
```

---

Result:

```
ALTER TABLE
UPDATE 12
UPDATE 8
UPDATE 8
 id | thread_id | previous_id | rnk |       subject       |         created_at         | folder |                                 message_id                                 
----+-----------+-------------+-----+---------------------+----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 |         1 |             |   1 | howzitgoin          | 2014-06-22 16:53:56.168109 |        | 53856b1448c89_23fa9605badd015951@3a139e8c-0b81-42c2-8e59-133c262e96a9.mail
  2 |         1 |           1 |   2 | Re: howzitgoin      | 2014-06-22 17:03:56.168109 | INBOX  | CAEBV8YTu_A6LtP_uGuQ-QSVj3zojWUiwcjGZpsPPEz1Pj3_i1A@mail.gmail.com
  3 |         1 |           1 |   3 | Re: howzitgoin      | 2014-06-22 17:13:56.168109 | INBOX  | 53856b88a2a09_23fa9605badd01601b@3a139e8c-0b81-42c2-8e59-133c262e96a9.mail
  4 |         1 |           1 |   4 | Re: howzitgoin      | 2014-06-22 17:23:56.168109 | INBOX  | CAEBV8YT6vx6buOKUga4f=bcNGq_=WzwiqEzm2FWm3HoLZ8SbJA@mail.gmail.com
  5 |         1 |           3 |   5 | Re: howzitgoin      | 2014-06-22 17:33:56.168109 | INBOX  | CAEBV8YRGwkNSb3cxquS5abSCmnwLn37GxCpg74mQe7=3SC5cdQ@mail.gmail.com
  6 |         6 |             |   1 | thready mercury     | 2014-06-22 17:43:56.168109 | INBOX  | 1401340841.22951.YahooMailNeo@web171602.mail.ir2.yahoo.com
  7 |         6 |           6 |   2 | RE: thready mercury | 2014-06-22 17:53:56.168109 |        | 5386c3c3f364d_23ff44def2de8849cf@55cedd07-f558-4cc4-b5d2-046dc7642b91.mail
  8 |         6 |           7 |   3 | RE: thready mercury | 2014-06-22 18:03:56.168109 | INBOX  | 1401340888.34275.YahooMailNeo@web171605.mail.ir2.yahoo.com
  9 |         9 |             |   1 | Not part of thread  | 2014-06-22 16:43:56.168109 | INBOX  | CAEBV8YRGwkNSb3cxquS5abSCmnwLn37GxCpg74mQe7=3SC5cdQ@mail.gmail.com
 10 |        10 |             |   1 | not returning       | 2014-06-22 16:03:56.168109 | INBOX  | CAEBV8YQ58oXAm9wqLz18J5RsV2fN9u__bnsp_Z8qhdEJpmt-EQ@mail.gmail.com
 11 |        10 |          10 |   2 | RE: not returning   | 2014-06-22 16:13:56.168109 |        | 538f82fc7e661_23f9fbee7c84825682@3b0c9abe-8e87-410f-895e-c132ff5f4be3.mail
 12 |        10 |          10 |   3 | RE: not returning   | 2014-06-22 16:23:56.168109 |        | 539024ecaa478_23fb766d5ca209988b@24b867e3-62f2-491b-a58a-660c87d0be57.mail
(12 rows)
```

---

UPDATE: it appears the OP is only intersted in the most recent email per thread (he should have put that in the question). Which is the one with the largest `rank()` for that thread, or the one that does not have a `lead()` value:

```
WITH xxx AS (
SELECT  id, thread_id, previous_id
        , rank() over (PARTITION BY thread_id ORDER BY created_at) AS rnk
        , lead(id) over (PARTITION BY thread_id ORDER BY created_at ) AS nxt
        , subject, created_at, folder ,message_id
        FROM emails
        )
SELECT id, thread_id, previous_id, rnk, subject, created_at, folder ,message_id
FROM xxx
WHERE nxt IS NULL
ORDER BY thread_id,created_at,id;
```

Result:

```
 id | thread_id | previous_id | rnk |       subject       |         created_at         | folder |                                 message_id                                 
----+-----------+-------------+-----+---------------------+----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  5 |         1 |           2 |   5 | Re: howzitgoin      | 2014-06-25 12:37:58.263205 | INBOX  | CAEBV8YRGwkNSb3cxquS5abSCmnwLn37GxCpg74mQe7=3SC5cdQ@mail.gmail.com
  8 |         6 |           6 |   3 | RE: thready mercury | 2014-06-25 13:07:58.263205 | INBOX  | 1401340888.34275.YahooMailNeo@web171605.mail.ir2.yahoo.com
  9 |         9 |             |   1 | Not part of thread  | 2014-06-25 11:47:58.263205 | INBOX  | CAEBV8YRGwkNSb3cxquS5abSCmnwLn37GxCpg74mQe7=3SC5cdQ@mail.gmail.com
 12 |        10 |          10 |   3 | RE: not returning   | 2014-06-25 11:27:58.263205 |        | 539024ecaa478_23fb766d5ca209988b@24b867e3-62f2-491b-a58a-660c87d0be57.mail
(4 rows)
```

Note that the `rnk` field is actually the highest rank for the thread == the number of messages in the thread.

Comment: How does this help showing #10? Its not the latest in its thread, but the only one in the inbox. OP wanted a query that returns #5, #8, #9 and #10.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer is right, you should not only be showing 1 email per thread

Comment: @dagda1 Currently he shows all emails per thread. I think his restructuring is well thought of - adding thread_id and previous_id into the email table is a good idea but it alone won't solve the problem.

Comment: The OP is not very clear in showing his intended output. It seems to me that only showing the latest message per thread (5,8,9,10) is fairly trivial, and could even be made conditional on `(not) folder = 'INBOX' ` . If that were intended.

Comment: @wildplasser, still not the output the OP desired as he wants only messages from the Inbox. #12 is not in the inbox. #10 should be shown instead (as the highest ranking message from that thread thats in the inbox). I agree with you that he should have been much more detailed in his requirements in the Question. It becomes clear what he wants through the comments, though.

Comment: He should specify what his intended results are. And not refer to "the same as what vendor XXX does"

Comment: @wildplasser He should have. Yes. I edited into the question but it would have been better if it had been there in the first place.